# Design Support Library V22 - No Sources?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

I can't find any sources for the new design support library.

I checked in the usual place:
`<android-sdk>/extras/android/support/design/src`

But there's nothing there.  Do I have to download something extra to get them?

Answer (score 0):

Here are (some of) the sources:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/

At this time, it doesn't seem complete with only the sources for some widgets such as TabLayout, but not Snackbar for instance.